# Converse to Weil Restriction of Scalars

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero (I'm only interested in number fields), and let $\mathbb{G}_{/k}$ be a linear algebraic group defined over $k$ which is almost $k$-simple (all normal subgroups defined over $k$ are finite).  This group need not be absolutely almost simple, and one way this situation can arise is when $\mathbb{G}$ is the Weil restriction of scalars of an almost-simple $K$-group defined over a finite extension $K/k$.  Is that the only possibility?

In other words, suppose $\mathbb{G}$ is $k$-almost simple. Is there a finite extension $K$ and an absolutely almost simple group $\mathbb{H}_{/K}$ such that $R^K_k\mathbb{H}$ is $k$-isogenous to $\mathbb{G}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Algebraic groups geometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb G_m^n$ are classified by homomorphisms from the Galois group to $\operatorname{Aut}( \mathbb G_m^n) = GL_n(\mathbb Z)$. Almost simple ones correspond to irreducible representations. You are asking whether the irreducible representations are induced representations of trivial representations - in fact induced representations are never irreducible, so the answer is no.

All other cases are fine, though:

Consider the group $G$ over an algebraically closed field. It has no proper canonical normal subgroups - ones definable using just the structure of the group, which would be definable over $k$. Hence it is either reductive or unipotent.

If unipotent, it must be abelian, hence of the form $\mathbb G_a^n$. Then it must be of the form $\mathbb G_a^n$ over $k$ by Hilbert 90, hence $k=1$ and we are done.

If reductive, it must be either a torus or semisimple. If semisimple it is isogenous to a product of copies of simple groups. The semisimple case is fine - there is a transitive Galois action on the set of simple factors, which you can use to write it as a Weil restriction from the field corresponding to the stabilizer of one of the factors. The torus case, as we saw earlier, is problematic.

Comment: I was thinking about semisimple groups: thanks for confirming my intuition.  It didn't occur to me that a torus could be almost simple, but of course it can be.

Comment: Not that it matters here, but as with finite groups (where "simple" usually includes "non-abelian") the usual convention is that "almost simple" in the context of linear algebraic groups is meant to include a semisimplicity hypothesis (as Lior intended). A literature reference for that case (with the same idea of proof as above) is 6.21(ii) in the Borel-Tits IHES paper on reductive groups, and this is proved there over any field at all (though Lior only wants char. 0).

Comment: More refined: if $G$ is a connected semisimple $k$-group that is simply connected (or adjoint) with $k$ any field then there is a pair $(k'/k,G')$ consisting of a finite etale $k$-algebra $k'$ and semisimple $k'$-group $G'$ with connected fibers that are absolutely simple and simply connected (or adjoint) so that ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}(G') \simeq G$, and moreover that this pair is unique up to *unique* isomorphism (i.e., isom between such Weil restrictions *uniquely* arises from $k$-algebra isom and group isom over that). By uniqueness and Galois descent we can assume $k=k_s$, which is easy!

Comment: @user74230 Does simple really mean non-abelian in the finite group case? Almost every reference I've seen includes $\mathbb Z/p$ among them.

Comment: Of course the Jordan-Holder theorem would be awkward to state if $\mathbf Z/(p)$ were not among the finite simple groups. I am sure user74230 only had in mind that when you talk about *classifying* the finite simple groups you may make a convention about them being non-abelian to avoid having to say that a lot. For instance, on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem I find the following quote from Burnside: "The contrast that these results show between groups of odd and even order suggests inevitably that simple groups of odd order do not exist."

Comment: @WillSawin: KConrad hit the nail on the head. Certainly from a strictly logical point of view the phrase "simple linear algebraic group" would include various unipotent groups and tori, but the features of the solvable case are so different from the much richer and more interesting and important semisimple case that it is usually implicit (e.g., Lior followed that convention!).   I am sure you already do this for complex Lie algebras.  And shouldn't "simple" imply "semisimple"? :)

Comment: @user74230 That's completely true but I think the appropriate conventions for Lie groups, Lie algebras, algebraic groups, and finite groups, are all slightly different. For instance, for many purposes in algebraic groups, reductive groups are more important than semisimple ones. The torus is an abelian group with semisimple representation theory, which doesn't exist in the Lie algebra context, but describes all finite abelian groups. Shouldn't a semisimple Tannakian category have a semisimple Tannakian group?

Comment: @WillSawin: The "Tannakian" argument doesn't seem particularly compelling, though could just be personal taste.  Lior's implicit preference expresses what happens to most who work seriously with reductive groups over a long period of time: "simple non-commutative" is a ubiquitous concept whereas "simple torus" is basically useless (as a general concept).  Thus, it is convenient to follow the same convention as for Lie algebras, wherein "simple" means "categorically simple" up to isogeny together with non-commutativity condition (much as usually "simple" means what some call "almost simple").